# Как реализовать аннотации @NonNull и @Positive

Tags: java, null, аннотации, java-8

Хотелось бы избавиться от NullPointerException и прочих ошибок с помощью аннотаций
например есть класс

```
class A{

public List<@NonNull String> list = new ArrayList();//здесь надо запретить чтобы в коллекцию попадали null значения

public Long compute(@Positive Integer num){//здесь разрешить только положит числа
// calculation ...
    return num;
}
```

создаю свои аннотации

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface NonNull {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface Positive{}
```

хорошо теперь в коде я использую этот класс

```
A a = new A();
String test = null;
Integer random = new Random().nextInt();
if ( random < 0 ){
        a.compute(random);
        a.list.add(test);
} else{
        test = "NonNull";
        a.list.add(test);
 }
```

мне понятно как с помощью Reflection можно перед инициализацией просканировать класс А и найти в нем эти аннотации, но не понятно что делать дальше как можно установить проверку уже в рабочем коде????

Comment: я вижу, @NonNull нужно применять не к параметру типа, а, к аргументам функции - аналога .add() .addAll() или конструктора.
А с методом compute не совсем понятно, чего хотите добиться аннотациями, ведь можно проверять и внутри метода:
`if (num.compareTo(0) <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException()`

Answer (score 3):

С помощью аннотаций валидировать данные можно двумя совершенно разными подходами:

1. В первом случае, аннотации служат в качестве подсказок для анализаторов кода. Они могут подсказать и показать места, в которых происходит явное нарушение ограничений. Более подробно можно ознакомиться с этим, на примере [checker framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/tutorial/webpages/get-started-eclipse.html)
2. Второй подход позволяет валидировать данные в режиме исполнения используя сторонний фреймворк. Примером этого может служить [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

В обоих случаях, с вашей стороны требуется только расставление аннотаций. Реализация проверок осуществляется сторонним инструментом.